# keystore file not found for signing config 'release'. - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make the app bundle for my app but this problem is always coming and i don't know what to do. My key.jks file is located in /Users/Ojas/key.jks
but still it is showing me this error. `enter code here`Kindly help

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Ojas\IdeaProjects\helper\android\app\Users\Ojas\key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

Comment: Copy and paste the Keystore file in your android/app folder then try again.

Comment: " \Users\Ojas\key.jks " ,this is mac os path naming convention, You're using Windows operating system so  please try windows path convention.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using a doublebackSlash(\) on storefile actually solves my issue.

storeFile=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\app\key.jks

NOTE: I DONT KNOW WHY BUT DOING DOUBLE BACKSLASH ON THE ANSWER HERE DOESNT WORK, JUST KEEP IN MIND THAT ALL THE BACKSLASH THAT I ENTERED HERE ARE DOUBLED